# Why is my Canon printer only printing half-pages?

Tags: printing, canon

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why did my Canon or Epson printer stop working after a recent update on 12.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/173229/why-did-my-canon-or-epson-printer-stop-working-after-a-recent-update-on-12-04)

Ubuntu 12.04, CUPS 1.5.3, Canon i550 printer configuration the i550, i560 and i850 prints on a half side only with a driver.

It's i550 driver from more viewpoints is unusable.

What should I do?