# Why did my Canon or Epson printer stop working after a recent update on 12.04?

Tags: upgrade, updates, printing, canon, epson

I have a Canon (or Epson) printer and use Ubuntu 12.04. It looks like my printer has partially stopped working after a recent update -- only half of the last page is printed out (sometimes this happens with all pages).

Is there a way to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem [was a known bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cups/+bug/1032456) with Ubuntu's printing subsystem (CUPS), introduced by a recent update towards the end of July.

**It has now been fixed (as of August 7, 2012).**

The fixed version should be installed as part of your regular *Update Manager* process within the next few days; **if you would like to fix it *now***, please do the following:

1. Open a terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.
2. Select and copy the below with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, and paste it in the terminal window by right-clicking inside it and then clicking on *Paste*:

   ```
   sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install cups
   ```

   Enter your password when asked.
3. This should fix the problem (a reboot may be needed for some). If you have this printing problem but get the message `cups is already the newest version.` when you try the above, please wait a few hours and try again - the updated version may not have made it to your local Ubuntu update server (mirror).

Comment: [I have exactly the same problem](http://askubuntu.com/q/476320/148451) on 14.04, but this solution didn't work for me. Any ideas...?

Comment: didnt work for me