# Printer prints half of page

Tags: 14.04, printing, pdf, canon

The printer (Canon PIXMA MP190) prints pages successfully - very clear - but I need to wait about 5 minutes for each page to be printed. It prints normally (fast) about one half of page, then it stops... The another half of page is printed very slowly.

I am running 14.04. In the previous versions (<= 13.10), the printer was working properly.

What can be the issue? The clarity?

I don't need such a good clarity, but I don't know how to change it.

How can I solve the problem?

> [image]

---

I have another machine running Elementary Isis Beta (that is based on Ubuntu 14.04, I guess). The printer works fine, being connected to that machine.

Relevant outputs:

```bash
# Elementary Isis Beta
$ uname -a
Linux ionica-desktop 3.13.0-29-generic #53-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jun 4 21:00:20 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
# The main machine, running Ubuntu 14.04, having the issue
$ uname -a
Linux laptop 3.13.0-29-generic #53-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jun 4 21:00:20 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Could you provide some details about the printer? What is the make and model? **Please edit your original question above with new information.**

Comment: @user68186 I updated it. Also, I attached a screenshot with the print window.

Comment: I don't have this printer. Please check the various tabs on top of the print window, such as Page Setup, Image Quality, etc. and see if the resolution can be changed. It should be something like "Output Resolution = 600dpi".

Comment: @user68186 `Image Quality -> Resolution <Automatic>` - what should I choose instead?

Comment: What other choices do you have? I am not sure if Image Quality will affect regular text. But there is no harm in trying. Try 600 or 300 DPI.

Comment: @user68186 I tried, but same story. *Image Quality* seems not to affect the text. BTW, I am printing a pdf that contains text only.

Comment: @user68186 How can I control how much ink is used? I guess this is the problem: the text is very clear, so there is used more ink than needed.

Comment: I have no idea how to control ink. Check the other tabs, Jobs, Co.or, Advanced etc. and see if you can find any other settings with 600dpi or 300dpi etc.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, your printer is [listed as a paperweight](http://www.openprinting.org/printer/Canon/Canon-PIXMA_MP190) by Open Printing. I take that to mean it will take a bit more work to get your printer up and running.

I did find [this old Ubuntu Forums thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1305248), which gave us some instructions on how to install the printer from Canon's provided files.

Anyway, you're supposed to:

1. Download [the .tar file](http://www.canon-europe.com/Support/Consumer_Products/products/Fax__Multifunctionals/InkJet/PIXMA_MP_series/PIXMA_MP190.aspx?type=download&softwaredetailid=tcm:13-738693&os=Linux&language=) from Canon. (Make sure you read and agree to the license agreement at that link.)

   ```
   wget http://files.canon-europe.com/files/soft31326/Software/MP190_debian_drivers.tar
   ```
2. Extract everything.

   ```
   tar -xf ./MP190_debian_drivers.tar
   tar -xf ./MP190_debian_printer.tar
   tar -xf ./MP190_debian_scangear.tar
   ```
3. Unpackage the driver. You need to modify the dependencies after.

   ```
   dpkg-deb -x cnijfilter-common_3.00-1_i386.deb common
   dpkg-deb --control cnijfilter-common_3.00-1_i386.deb
   ```
4. Open the file named `control` in the new DEBIAN folder with a text editor. Here I use `nano`, but you can use `gedit`, `kate`, `leafpad`, or `what have you`.

   ```
   nano ./DEBIAN/control
   ```
5. One Line 6, which lists `Depends:`, change `libcupsys2` to `libcups2`. There is no need to change anything else, though it can be mildly amusing to change the `Description:`. Save and quit.
6. Copy the `DEBIAN` folder into the `common` folder/

   ```
   cp -R ./DEBIAN ./common
   ```
7. Repackage the driver.

   ```
   dpkg -b common cnijfilter-common_3.00-1_i386.deb
   ```
8. Clean up.

   ```
   rm -r ./common ./DEBIAN
   ```
9. Repeat the process of unpackaging, modifying, and repackaging for `cnijfilter-mp190series_3.00-1_i386.deb`.

In short:

```
wget http://files.canon-europe.com/files/soft31326/Software/MP190_debian_drivers.tar
tar -xf ./MP190_debian_drivers.tar
tar -xf ./MP190_debian_printer.tar
dpkg-deb -x cnijfilter-common_3.00-1_i386.deb common
dpkg-deb --control cnijfilter-common_3.00-1_i386.deb
sed -i 's/libcupsys2/libcups2/' ./DEBIAN/control
cp -R ./DEBIAN ./common
dpkg -b common cnijfilter-common_3.00-1_i386.deb
rm -r ./common ./DEBIAN
dpkg-deb -x cnijfilter-mp190series_3.00-1_i386.deb common
dpkg-deb --control cnijfilter-mp190series_3.00-1_i386.deb
sed -i 's/libcupsys2/libcups2/' ./DEBIAN/control
cp -R ./DEBIAN ./common
dpkg -b common cnijfilter-mp190series_3.00-1_i386.deb
rm -r ./common ./DEBIAN
sudo dpkg -i ./cnijfilter-*.deb
```